# SpaceX Dragon: How many fuel tanks?

Tags: fuel, dragon-v2, tanks

I've read that Dragon carries 1380 kg of MMH + NTO propellant. This mass would be split among the various tanks, and I'm wondering---how many of them are there?

Pictures from the manufacturing floor show twelve compartments arranged in a circular array just beneath the entrance door... Each compartment is large enough to hold a tank, so 12 is the maximum they would carry.

And I believe I've seen eight red tanks and either two or four gray tanks in those compartments, though I'm not sure any more. My thought has been the red tanks were fuel and the gray tanks were oxygen for the crew or maybe some inert gas (point being: not fuel).

If there are eight fuel tanks, than four would be MMH and four would be NTO. But can someone say for sure if there are eight fuel tanks? Also would appreciate more insight into the gray tanks, as I still don't know exactly what they'd carry.

Will try to find and post pictures of the tanks but if you know the answer, please do share.